# Connect to LinuxKit with ssh from Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

I can build and run LinuxKit with Windows 10 or Ubuntu 18.04. But when I try to connect with ssh the connection is dropped. I tried both the ssh example and the regular "linuxkit.yml" examples. How should I set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest is to start with the sshd image. On Windows 10 Professional or Windows 10 Enterprise you can build the image as follows:

```
linuxkit.exe build -format iso-efi sshd.yml
```

Then you run the image, maybe in Git BASH or some other shell which respects the `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` variable:

```
linuxkit.exe run -disk size=1 -name=linuxssh sshd-efi.iso
```

If all goes well, the linuxkit now boots and you can ssh into linuxkit from another terminal window, using the ip number you see in the LinuxKit when you run ifconfig.